# Access variable by string inside function

Tags: javascript

I want to check out whether the arguments provided in a function are strings and for this I'm using the following condition:

```
function someFunction (variable1, variable2, variable3) {
   ["variable1", "variable2", "variable3"].forEach(function (each) {
      if (!(/*something*/[each].constructor.name === "String")) throw new TypeError(
         each + " must be a string. " + /*something*/[each].constructor.name +
         " was given instead."
      );
      else ...
   });
}
```

Had the check occurred in the global namespace, I could've used **`window[each]`**, since variables are properties of **`window`**, like below:

```
var variable1, variable2, variable3;

["variable1", "variable2", "variable3"].forEach(function (each) {
   if (!(window[each] instanceof String)) throw new TypeError(
      each + " must be a string. " + window[each].constructor.name + " was given instead."
   );
   else ...
});
```

How can the above be achieve inside a function?

Comment: There's no way to access local variables by name. `window[name]` can only be used with global variables, there's nothing equivalent for local variables.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to allow strings, right? If so - use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), typeof and the code below:

```
function someFunction(variable1, variable2, variable3) {
    [].forEach.call(arguments, function(each) {
        console.log(typeof each);
        if (typeof each != 'string') {
            throw new TypeError(
                each + " must be a string. " + /*something*/ each.constructor.name +
                " was given instead."
            );
        } else {
            console.log("its a string")
        }
    });
}

someFunction("foo", "bar", ["baz"])
```

Answer (score 1):

inside `forEach`, `each` loops over the variables

```
function someFunction (variable1, variable2, variable3) {
   [variable1, variable2, variable3].forEach(function (each) {
      if (!(each.constructor.name === "String")) throw new TypeError(
         each + " must be a string. " + each.constructor.name +
         " was given instead."
      );
      else ...
   });
}
```

Comment: Fixed to use the variables. Not sure what OP is asking for.

Comment: Your answer works fine @JeromeWAGNER. I edited the condition inside **`if`**, because it only accepted strings created through **`String()`**.